# How to create a random data API

Tags: php, json, api, random

I want to create a server side API that returns random data from a text file list. And when user call that api, random data from each set of list is displayed (but data from each set should match each other) . Something like the [random user generator API](https://randomuser.me/). So basically I have 2 lists:

**Names** (Names.txt)

```
John
Andy
James
```

**Family Name** (Family.txt)

```
Doe
Candy
Mill
```

and the basic random return json file when calling the API (api.server.com/?format=json) is :

```
{
  "name":"John",
  "family":"Doe"
}
```

I can't find any good tutorials on how to do this on my own server. I have found many websites which offer similar services but I want to create my own.

**Update:** I want every name to match exactly a specific family name. For example json output is first name and first last name, an other call outputs second name and second last name and etc.

Can someone points me to the right direction on how to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to know from us.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I think he wants us to do a Google search and find a tutorial for him.

Comment: so basically where do I start? I am not even sure how to approach this problem

Comment: @HelmutGranda no I have done that already, I can't find a tutorial on how to generate random list from two lists

Comment: Basically you just need to write a script which reads the 2 files in an array, shuffle it, take the first element and return it as json.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois yes, I forgot to mention in the question that json output is random but lists should match each other. For example first name and first last name, second name and second last name. So shuffle the array will not work

Comment: Do you mean if I take the second element of the name list, I also have to take the second element of the family name list? If so you could generate a random number in the range of the count of the elements in the array of the names and then use that number to return the correct rows of both lists.

Comment: @RobertA: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/93275-how-can-i-randomly-combine-the-elements-of-two-arrays-in-matlab-7-5-r2007b

Comment: @CharlotteDunois yes, exactly. So create a random number, lets say 2, then look at list A, return row 2, look at list B and return row 2, combine these two in an array and make json file?

Comment: There you go. Functions you need to use for this: `file()`, `count()`, `mt_rand()`, `json_encode()` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the files into arrays with `file()`, generate a random number and use it as key to get a random name from the arrays. Use `json_encode()` to convert the array to JSON.

```
<?php

$name   = file('Names.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$family = file('Family.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

$rand   = rand(0, count($name)-1);

$result = array('name'   => $name[$rand],
                'family' => $family[$rand]);

echo json_encode($result);

?>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are highly discouraged. Please add text to explain what it does.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what do you want, but I hope this post help you.

I've created several APIs with CodeIgniter and the library REST_CONTROLLER, it's too easy and you can find some tutorials about that.

Then, I was going to write some code like Emil's code, but he did it.

Regards!